# what causes the Connection reset by peer error

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, connection

I have a flex application that is getting data via httpservice calls to an asp application.I am getting the Connection reset by peer 104, (502 bad gateway ) error. This happens randomly and its not always on the same httpservice. Am sure this is a connection problem , how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This means that server has sent you RST packet what means that immediate dropping of the connection has happened.

> "Connection reset by peer" is the TCP/IP equivalent of slamming the
>   phone back on the hook. It's more polite than merely not replying,
>   leaving one hanging. But it's not the FIN-ACK expected of the truly
>   polite TCP/IP converseur."

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me in a case where 2 devices were sharing the same IP due to misconfiguration. It was very a frustrating error because one could be transferring a large file and for most of the time everything would work just fine but at random times the connection was dropped. Testing with iperf showed that both sides were getting an RST packet every once in a while.

My guess is that at some point packets destined to an open session with device-A where delivered to device-B and device-B not finding an existing session for them was sending back a RST packet.